# How to get all required strings in a string array before a break

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops

We were given a task to make a program  that takes the input of the user. there two types of input the user can use, 1st is the "Type in the Size" and the second is "Type in the style" either way the user can just input in the 1st field or the 2nd field. when the users clicks ok the two inputs will be use to sortout a arraylist which contains the type of size and style in it.

```
public void viewResult(String style, String size) {
    style = style.toLowerCase();
    size = size.toLowerCase();
    new_list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Items_container items:current_arrayList)
        {
                if (items.getStyle().toLowerCase().contains(style) && items.getSize().toLowerCase().contains(size)) 
                {
                        new_list.add(items);
                        break;

                }
                else if (items.getSize().toLowerCase().contains(size)) {
                        new_list.add(items);
                        break;

                }

                else if (items.getStyle().toLowerCase().contains(style)) {
                       new_list.add(items);
                       break;
            }
        }

    current_arraylist.clear();
    adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
    if (new_list.size() == 0) {
        results.setText("Search not found");
    } else {
        results.setText("Results");
    }
}
```

this is the method that I use to sortout out the Items_container now it does work fine (I guess)

but the problem is for example the user inputs "large" in the size input field and "blazzing" in the style input field the program must sort the items_container using the given inputs but it is not working because the program  also includes all the items that has the same size or the same style.

I tried adding a break to the loop but now it only shows one data and what if there two or more data that matches the givens inputs, how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you have one OR block instead of the 3 conditions you have above?

Comment: So how will i diffenciate the conditions that way?

Comment: Only have the first condition but put || instead of &&.

Comment: oh ok i guess that more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if both conditions are set. That way you can separate if either one matches and if both match. Maybe put singular matches in a separate list in case no items match both conditions, but that's up to you.

And as others already said, break stops the loop, continue moves to the next item.

Answer (score -1):

like code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <current_arrayList.size() ; i++) {
                if(current_arrayList.get(i).getStyle().toLowerCase().contains(style)
                        && current_arrayList.get(i).getSize().toLowerCase().contains(size))
                {
                    new_list.add(current_arrayList.get(i));
                    //if used break ,stop loop 

                }
                else if (current_arrayList.get(i).getSize().toLowerCase().contains(size)) {
                    new_list.add(current_arrayList.get(i));

                }

                else if (current_arrayList.get(i).getStyle().toLowerCase().contains(style)) {
                    new_list.add(current_arrayList.get(i));

                }
            }
            current_arraylist.clear();
            adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: just a simple question, if did use break it stop at the 1st loop is it right? so how do I stop it at the last loop?